# why onclick handler didnt work when it use with innerHTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.innerHTML = "aaaa";
    document.body.appendChild(para);

    var bspan = document.createElement("span");
    bspan.innerHTML = "bbbb";
    para.appendChild(bspan);

    bspan.onclick = function(){
       alert("hi");
    }
    para.innerHTML += "cccc";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code, I expect it to alert hi when I clicked on bbbb, but it obviously not functioning, why?

Comment: Did you mean for `spa` to be `bspan`?  (typo in 2 places)

Comment: @SteveHoward corrected but still didnt work

Comment: If you comment the `para.innerHTML += "cccc"`, it works.  I wanted to throw that out there for your information.  I'm still working this.

Comment: ok, thanks @MikeMarks but, why this could happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not using jQuery, Here is the simple example of event delegation using javascript as your `span` element is generated from code so give this a try:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
  var el = event.target;
  if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span") {
    alert("hi");
  }
};
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bh95e/1/)

Comment: can i know why my code dont work??

Comment: It is because you are creating `span` at runtime. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) is the valuable post to understand it.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak, if you comment out the `para.innerHTML += "cccc";`, then it works.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: I have the same question with @MikeMarks

Comment: A stronger hint would be that `para.innerHTML += "cccc"` is actually a shorthand for `para.innerHTML = para.innerHTML + "cccc"`.  If you take a look at `para.innerHTML` before you try to change it, you might figure out why this line drops your event handler.

Comment: @MikeMarks Let's say the browser creates dom objects/Text from innerHTML and after that you add a listener to that dom element. That's why we are delegating the event :) Hope this is clear!

Comment: @SteveHoward sorry I still can't get it

Comment: @DhavalMarthak ur method is fine for my code, but if i want to add another span and when i click on that span it will alert hi too

Comment: @dramasea You may check for the className or ID along with nodeName according to your need. E.G. `if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span" && el.className == "myClass")`

Comment: @dramasea can you mark the answer as accepted if it's helful to you?

Answer (score 2):

short answer, the error i get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: spa is not defined`, so you need to define spa first.

Comment: corrected but still didnt work

Comment: it is, his question is why is it not functioning. Not sure why the downvote.

Comment: @ZachSpencer, did you really not know that he meant `bspan`?  I don't know, I saw what you saw and immediately knew that's what he meant, but if you didn't, you know, that explains your answer.

Comment: @Mike Why does need to be hashed out? Why should I assume that `spa` was a typo? You need to let this one go Mike, its one answer out of millions.

Comment: @ZachSpencer - It needs to be hashed out because if you knowingly understood (or at least had a decent idea) what he really meant yet you put this as the answer just to be facetious, it's not exactly answering his question, though sure, technically this is an answer - it just came across as you didn't really pay attention to his question, or you're just trying to be a smart ass.  It doesn't take a genius to figure out what he meant, and this answer wasn't exactly the most thought out.  Understand the root of the question before posting an answer like this.